# Why is ASP.NET Core Identity not recommended for web api authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, identity, .net-6.0

Instead the docs recommend Identity Server, Azure AD, etc for securing Web Apis. As far as I can tell, Identity offers JWT as well, so why is it not recommended?

Here is a link to the docs recommending Identity Server and Azure AD ([https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#:~:text=To%20secure%20web%20APIs%20and%20SPAs%2C%20use%20one%20of%20the%20following%3A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#:%7E:text=To%20secure%20web%20APIs%20and%20SPAs%2C%20use%20one%20of%20the%20following%3A)

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. Identity in Web API works great. So does Azure AD, but it's not right for every project. Same with Identity Server. I wonder if Microsoft is planning to deprecate Identity.

Comment: I opened an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/27913